# How to generate sample data based on the existing Avro schema?

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, data-generation, stub-data-generation

I am doing performance testing of Kafka and need to test different large schemas. At the moment, I am working on Avro-based load testing.

Usually, when working with Kafka, you have data and generate a schema from that. I must test several schemas in this scenario, for which I don't own data. I need to generate sample Avro data based on the existing schema.

What are the possible solutions?

Tried solutions:

- I have tried making data manually, but it is too tedious.
- Searched for auto-generators with no luck
- Searched official Kafka documentation for the possible solution
- I tried writing my own but have little experience with Avro, so it seems too custom and non-maintainable to continue

How to generate sample data based on the existing Avro schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are comfortable with Python the `fastavro` library has utilities to generate data from the schema: https://fastavro.readthedocs.io/en/latest/utils.html

As an example:

```py
from fastavro.utils import generate_many

schema = {
    'doc': 'A weather reading.',
    'name': 'Weather',
    'namespace': 'test',
    'type': 'record',
    'fields': [
        {'name': 'station', 'type': 'string'},
        {'name': 'time', 'type': 'long'},
        {'name': 'temp', 'type': 'int'},
    ],
}

print(list(generate_many(schema, 5)))
```